# Confusion found with and operator

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I get following output with `and` operator

**code**

```
>>>0 and []
0
>>>[] and 0
[]
>>> 0 and ''
0
>>>'' and 0
''
```

I could not figure out about on what basis I m getting different result on the basis of placing of elements..

Comment: `x and y` is equivalent to `y if x else x`. Similar, `x or y` is `x if x else y` which is handy for assigning default values.

Comment: It's not clear to me why Martijn Pieters marked this a duplicate of short circuiting.  This has nothing to do with short circuiting.  Truthiness is not an issue of short circuiting, and the answer in Python would be the same with or without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#and) on `and`:

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

In your case, because `0`, `''`, and `[]` all evaluate to `False`, the first value in each of your expressions is being returned.

Comment: Wow, you somehow managed to post this 11 seconds after the question was closed. :-)

Comment: @tobias_k: there is a 4 hour window, actually. The *full web UI* disables the post button, but the mobile UI does not. If you started posting before the question got closed, you can still get in.