# Python: How to check if two lists are not empty

Tags: python, list

In Python, I know the pythonic way to check if a list is empty is

```
if not a:
    # do things with empty list
```

To check if a list is not empty then, we would do:

```
if a:
    # do things with my list
```

How would we check, simultaneously (as read), if two lists then are not empty?

```
if a and b:
    # do things with my two lists
```

The above does not seem to work, and I'm unsure what `(a and b)` actually means. For `a = [2]`, `b = [1,3]`, `(a and b) = [1,3]`. What is the `and` operator actually doing here? If I end up reducing `b = []` at some point, `(a and b) = []` even though `a` is not empty.

Edit: My use case goes something like

```
while (a and b are not empty):
    modify a
    modify b
```

I would have naively thought that since `if a` checks if a list is not empty, `if a and b` would check if neither were empty, which is not the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion found with and operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369368/confusion-found-with-and-operator)

Comment: what do you mean when you say "does not .. work"?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding,`if a and b:` will only be True if both are not empty

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more concise and check out the duplicate. This one is hard to search for as 'and' is typically not indexed.

Comment: `if a and b` does check whether or not both lists are empty. If your seeing things that seem otherwise, your problem is in your loop and not the conditional.

Comment: When you say `while (a and b are not empty):`, you you mean "while a is not empty and b is not empty", or "while at least one list is not empty"? e.g. The first will stop the loop when a==[1,2,3] and b==[], but the second will continue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's working fine. For `a = [2]` and `b = [1, 3]`, `a and b` is returning `[1, 3]` which is truthy, exactly as you would expect, because `True and True` is `True`. When you change `b` to `[]` it returns `[]`, which is falsy, again exactly as you would expect, because `True and False` is `False`. So `if a and b` does exactly what you want.

What is actually happening is that `and` is returning *the value that decided the truth of the expression.* `and` doesn't always evaluate both sub-expressions; when the first is falsy, the whole expression is falsy and the second doesn't need to be evaluated, and therefore isn't. This is called short-circuiting. `or` behaves similarly (skipping evaluating the second part if the first part is truthy). Wherever `and` or `or` is able to make its decision, it returns that value.

Another way of looking at it: `bool(a) and bool(a) == bool(a and b)` in Python.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, makes sense. Is there a better way to check if the two are not-empty than by checking their lengths?

Comment: Yes. `if a and b` as you originally had it.

Answer (score 2):

`a and b` is correct.

`and` returns the second argument if the first is true.

Comment: the second comment, while true is only meaningful outside of an if (like an assignment)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
if len(a) and len(b):
    #do something
```

Comment: I've thought about this, but am wondering if there's something closer to `a and b`. If not, I'll settle for it, but I'd still like to know what the operator is actually doing here.

Comment: Can you give an example where this would have different behavior from `if a and b:`?

Comment: @Kevin, should there be such a situation?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper this works because `if a and b` works. This is *exactly* the same as `if a and b`, only longer.

Comment: @ForceBru, if there's no such situation, then why use it over `if a and b:`?

Comment: There is no reason to use this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
>>> a, b = list(), list()
>>> while not (a and b):
...    a.append(1)
...    b.append(2)
...
>>> a, b
([1], [2])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`and` operator is compare two boolean values

```
    bool([]) == False
```

so `[] and b` always return `[]`; no matter what `b` is.

Answer (score 0):

To build on kindall's answer - you could also concatenate the lists before doing the truthiness test:

```
a = []
b = []
c = [1]
bool(a + b)  # False
bool(a + b + c)  # True
```

Of course this would come with a performance penalty if you were doing something where that mattered.